# iOS: how to instantiate YTPlayerView programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, ytplayerview

I'm trying to instantiate the YTPlayerView from the youtube_ios_player_helper pod programmatically, with the following code:

```
let player = YTPlayerView()
   player.cueVideo(byId: "someId", startSeconds: 0)
```

then the needed constraints are created and the youtubeplayer view is added to the containerview.

But, the internal webview, remains for ever nil, and is not created. I suppose I'm not instantiating the player correctly, but I did not found any information about how to do it.

Any Help?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/blob/master/Classes/YTPlayerView.m), `cueVideoById` does not actually create the internal webview, you need to first call one of the following:

```
- (BOOL)loadWithVideoId:(NSString *)videoId
- (BOOL)loadWithPlaylistId:(NSString *)playlistId
- (BOOL)loadWithVideoId:(NSString *)videoId playerVars:(NSDictionary *)playerVars
- (BOOL)loadWithPlaylistId:(NSString *)playlistId playerVars:(NSDictionary *)playerVars
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be creating an object `player` of `YTPlayerView`, BUT, it gets deallocated easily. So what to do? Make that a property. Something like this:

```
private lazy var player: YTPlayerView = {
    return YTPlayerView()
}()

override func viewDidLoad()...
```

or

```
private var player: YTPlayerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.player = YTPlayerView()
}
```